# Kubernetes pod vpnkit-controller keeps restarting

Tags: kubernetes

I've just enabled docker desktop's kubernetes feature on my m2 macbook air, and I observed that the `vpnkit-controller` pod under `kube-system` namespace has restarted several times since enabling the feature, is this normal or I missed some of the settings?

[screen shot of pod status](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HnGmH.png)

Comment: better to add logs of the pod, `kubectl logs -f pod_name`

Comment: logs of the pod only shows that `Starting kube-vpnkit-forwarder...`

Comment: may be something helpful in describe `kubectl describe pod`

Comment: The command returns logs [here](https://jpst.it/2ZuMg), but I only found error code 2 and don't know what happened.

Comment: I got error like "Port xxxx for service XXXXX is already opened by another service". no matter what port I use

Answer (score 2):

### Update:

This problem was resolved after upgrading Docker-Desktop to version `4.20.1`

which uses a new `docker/desktop-vpnkit-controller` image tagged with `dc331cb22850be0cdd97c84a9cfecaf44a1afb6e`

---

### Original Answer

you can get the log of crashed `vpnkit-controller` pod via command as follow:

```bash
kubectl logs -p -n kube-system vpnkit-controller
```

this shows me as follows

```
2023/03/09 03:45:54 Starting kube-vpnkit-forwarder...
W0309 04:03:37.888472       1 reflector.go:334] github.com/moby/vpnkit/go/cmd/kube-vpnkit-forwarder/main.go:49: watch of *v1.Service ended with: The resourceVersion for the provided watch is too old.
log: exiting because of error: log: cannot create log: open /tmp/kube-vpnkit-forwarder.vpnkit-controller.unknownuser.log.WARNING.20230309-040337.1: no such file or directory
```

Comment: The same here. Most recent Docker as of now Docker Desktop 4.19.0 (106363) on Windows 10 with WSL. Did you solve your problem somehow?